# how to check from which viewcontroller it has been navigated ....in obj c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, navigation

I am in a context where From some 3 classes I am navigating to a class say classX, and I have a back button on classX, on click of that back button I need to navigate to the class from which it has been navigated, so I need to check from which viewcontroller its been navigated, is it possible to do with out using **`UINavigationController`** ?

Comment: Aren't you using UINavigationController?

Comment: @AdilSoomro no i am not using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would check whether the type of the presenting view controller is the type you expect via:

```
if ([self.navigationController.presentingViewController isKindOfClass:[ParentController class]]) {
     ...
}
```